# How do I transfer a LinkedIn business page I created for a firm, to a new administrator?

Tags: linkedin, linkedin-groups

When I created the business page for my client, it was linked to my personal LinkedIn profile.  I need to transfer the business page to a new employee who will be hosting/managing/administrating the firm business page.  How do I do this transfer and ensure that the new admin does not see my personal profile.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Admin tools** > **Manage admins** from the page.

From there you can add and remove admins and change their roles.

So you would add the new employee as a super admin of the page and then after that you can remove yourself as an admin.